# Selenium + Python "clear fields"

Tags: python, selenium

I got a little problem with selenium-rc. After using selenium .type method on all fields, and trying login into this page - somethimes page return me again login page with clear fields... Any1 got idea whats wrong?

Page: http://obs.travco.co.uk/trboundj/

```
    SeleniumHelper.refresh_and_wait()
    SeleniumHelper.click("css=input[id='txtagentcode']")
    SeleniumHelper.type("css=input[id='txtagentcode']",self.authorization_data.LOGIN)
    SeleniumHelper.click("css=input[id='txtusercode']")
    SeleniumHelper.type("css=input[id='txtagentpwd']", self.authorization_data.PASSWORD)
    SeleniumHelper.click("css=input[id='txtusercode']")
    SeleniumHelper.type("css=input[id='txtusercode']", self.authorization_data.CODE)
    SeleniumHelper.click_and_wait("css=.contentbtn")
```